# How do you make ignore watch regex work in pm2

Tags: pm2

I have a environment.json setup for use with PM2.

My directory layout, relative to the directory I am calling pw2 is

`server
   |-- test
   |-- mock
api
pdf
csv
app
bower_components
node_modules`

I am only interested in watching changes in server (except test and mock directories) api, pdf and csv - none of the others.

So in my environment.json file I have the following three lines

`"watch" : ["server", "api", "pdf" ,"csv" ],
      "ignore-watch" : ["^.*\/test\/.*$", "^.*\/mock\/.*$"],
      "watch-options": {"followSymlinks" : false},`

but I just tested writing to a file in the mock directory, and my application restarted.

What am I doing wrong, and do I need such a heavy weight regex (I am not sure of the context of the match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way, just watch what you want with glob patterns:

```
watch: ['server', 'api', 'pdf' ,'csv', '!server/{test,mock}']
```

Or just ignore those:

```
watch: ['server', 'api', 'pdf' ,'csv'],
ignore_watch: ['server/test', 'server/mock']
```

With globs:

```
watch: ['server', 'api', 'pdf' ,'csv'],
ignore_watch: 'server/{test,mock}'
```

FIY, this is directly sent to [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar). Globs are handled by [micromatch](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/micromatch) (see [anymatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anymatch)).

Comment: Thanks - much simpler, but the real error was that I used ignore-watch when it should have been ignore_watch